# visual studio doesnt catch ThreadAbortException

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, threadabortexception

I've set up ThreadAbortException in the VS debug exceptions dialog, but it never breaks, even if I Thread.Abort() explicitly in my code.

I can see entries in the console such as:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in System.dll
An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Is there any way to get VS to break on these exceptions? (I'm using VS Express 2012 for desktop, but have access to the full VS if needed)

Answer (score 0):

[Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt.aspx)() calls End() which throws a ThreadAbortException exception upon completion. This is one source of such exceptions.

To break on exceptions select
Debug->Exceptions and for the Common Language Runtime Exceptions place a check in the Thrown column.

You can verify your settings are correct by running this sample code in a console application. The debugger should halt at the point where the thread is aborted.

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AbortThread
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            Task.Run( () => Thread.CurrentThread.Abort() );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I said in the original question - I already have ThreadAbortException selected in the debug exceptions, but it still never breaks.

Comment: Is there a check in the Thrown column?